# Change in Machine Key causes IE login cookie to stop working

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, cookies

I just moved to new servers and created a new machine key for all servers in the farm. Since then IE has been giving problems with the login cookies and even if the login username and password are correct, it doesn't let the user login.

The only way you can login is by clearing IE8 cache from the IE8 development tools. Is it possible to enforce browsers to accept the new cookie generate and discard their old cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is just 12 years but worth answering.
The problem is that your aspnet application will receive the cookie and it will fail to decrypt it as it was previously encrypted with a different key.
In your application you need to intercept the incoming request, try to decrypt it, and in case of failure remove the cookie from the request and carry on.
The cookie will be eventually re created, well this depends on your application, the authentication might fail and the user could be redirected to the authentication page.

In older applications you can do it in Global.asax Application_BeginRequest.